# User's guide for GoogleTest Runner Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, googletest

I already have several unitary test written with google test within my solution.
I've just install the "GoogleTest Runner" visual studio extension (2013).

I did not found any user's guide. 
Could somesone tell me how to use this extension, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, it took me a while to figure out how to use it as well. The extension integrates with the unit testing facilities that are built-in to visual studio, so when it's enabled you should be able to just click TEST->Run->All tests and it will pick up your test cases automatically.

One of the little hidden details is that the project containing the test cases must be named {something}Test, otherwise the plugin won't know where to look for the test cases.